# jQuery is not re enable textboxes on button click after add ui-css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, input

```
$("#button1").on("click", function () {
    $("input[type=text]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

$("#button2").on("click", function () {
    $("input:disabled").each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Above is working fine. But I make jQuery-ui for textboxes and ...... 
I have put code to disable all text boxes on document load. It works perfect.
But after I click on button, I want to enable all text boxes which are disabled on load.
My code as below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=text]").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $("#button2").on("click", function () {
        $("input:disabled").each(function () {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    });

});
```

It won't work and it remains textboxes disabled when I click on button.

See the Demo http://jsfiddle.net/kfHmX/

Comment: which browser you are using? I tried 1.9.1 and 2.0.2 are both working fine as your described using Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .prop() to set the disabled state

```
$("input:text").prop("disabled", true);//to disable

$("input:text").prop("disabled", false);//to enable
```

But since you are using jQuery UI use the [disable](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-disable) and [enable](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-enable) method to update the button UI

```
$("input:text").button("disable");

$("input:text").button("enable");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZkMJn/)

Comment: You demo is not working under IE10 but working in chromium, and by the I am struggling to find out the reason. Am I missing something.?

Comment: It is perfectly working under IE11. unfortunately I have only IE11. Try using as follows; `$("input[type=text]").button("disable");`

Answer (score 2):

Try out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kfHmX/1/ I hope this will work fine

instead of this

```
      $('input:text')
```

change it to this

```
    $('input:[type:text]')
```

Comment: This is wrong. you have change the Jquery-UI and it is not applying for text boxes.